# How can I set the appearance of section headings for a grouped style UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, fonts

I've got a `UITableView` that is setup using the 'Grouped' style, however I want to change the font, colour and size of the headings. Where would I be able to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement `UITableViewDelegate`’s `viewForHeaderInSection:` method.

See [Apple’s documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: And note that, per the specs, “this method only works correctly when `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` is also implemented.”